# Number of permutations that strictly contain three consecutive vowels

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Given the string "ENGINEER", how might one find the number of
>   permutations that contain only three consecutive vowels?

Same question for 2 consecutive vowels can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019396/number-of-permutations-that-strictly-contain-two-consecutive-vowels/2019437#2019437). I tried to solve this in the same way as given below.

Arrange the $4$ consonants:  $\dfrac{4!}{2!}$
Choose $2$ slots: $\dbinom{5}{2}$
One slot from the above is for the group of $3$ vowels: $\dbinom{2}{1}$
Arrange the $4$ vowels $\dfrac{4!}{3!}$

Their product is coming to $960$

But, actual answer is $1200$ (I tested using a java program).

Please help to understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: Check that your java code isn't counting the cases with four consecutive vowels as valid.

Comment: @thanks, it was the problem. i used a regular expression ^.*?[EI][EI][EI].*?$ which counted 3 and 4 together. so my calculation was right and program was wrong.

Comment: as per this community guidelines, please let me know if this question need to be deleted.